# ASPxGridView paging issue

Tags: asp.net, callback, devexpress, aspxgridview

I have an ASPxGridView and 2 radio buttons on my project. When I change selection of the radio button group, it changes the select command of the data source. After that, when I clicked on 2nd page, the data source's select command changes into previous situation.

Here is the example..
http://www.2shared.com/file/HwnBYcFS/WebApplication8.html

Note: When the page loads data source filters 'Neo's, click on the "All" radio button, and change the page.

Thanks for answers..

Comment: Prehaps it is not stored in the Viewstate? Or is it excuting a piece code to return it to the previous situation?

Comment: It should not execute, but I didn't understand is it executing. Did you try the example?

Comment: No i can't try it on this pc. Have you tried looking if it is saved in viewstate?

Comment: I have no idea how to do it. Can you explain it for me?

Comment: btw the 2 radio buttons you use are those devexpress controls aswell?

Comment: yes, they are ASPxRadioButton.

Comment: EnableViewState properties is True then i suppose? And AutoPostBack False? And does anything change if you put AutoPostBack on True?

Comment: EnableViewState property is True and I change AutoPostBack but nothing changed.

Comment: What about manualy saving the datasource in viewstate and on the load event of the datasource set the value to the value of the datasource in the viewstate? In the gridview if you got back to the first page is the same radio button stil selected or does that reset aswell?

Comment: Ah good ^^ You should answer your own qeustion with the sulotion so other people can solved this problem if they have the same problem and then you can except your own answer as answer so everyone can see it is already solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.add init event handler to grid
2.implement init event handler

```
protected void Grid_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsCallback)
        Page.Session["selectCommand"] = null;

    if (Page.Session["selectCommand"] != null)
        AccessDataSource1.SelectCommand = (string)Page.Session["selectCommand"];
    grid.DataBind();
}
```

3.Change custom callback handler

```
protected void grid_CustomCallback(object sender, ASPxGridViewCustomCallbackEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Parameters == "Neo")
    {
        AccessDataSource1.SelectCommand = "select Name,Surname from Person where Name='Neo'";
    }
    else if (e.Parameters == "All")
    {
        AccessDataSource1.SelectCommand = "select Name, Surname from Person";
    }
    Page.Session["selectCommand"] = AccessDataSource1.SelectCommand;
    grid.DataBind();
}
```

4.use CheckedChange client side event instead of gotfocus

```
<ClientSideEvents CheckedChanged="
    function(s, e)         
    {
        if(s.GetValue())
            grid.PerformCallback(&quot;Neo&quot;);
    }" />
```

Comment: I have a question. When I use CheckedChanged event, it fires the function 2 times. Because of it I use got focus event. Does it cause a problem?

Comment: Is it fired twice per radio button or one time for each radio button? Important thing is that grid callback is fired once.

Comment: Yes, for each radio button. So grid callback fires twice.

Comment: @erdincozdemir, grid_CustomCallback method is called only once in my project.